# How to get the pixels on a form drawn from the paint event?

Tags: c#, forms, pixel

I want to be able to get the pixels that are drawn on the form from the paint event. I've tried:

```
public Bitmap bmp;
```

Then later:

```
bmp = new Bitmap(this.BackgroundImage);
```

And then I could loop through the pixels:

```
for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
    {
        bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work, and I was wondering if anyone knew another way to do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(Warning: gross simplifications ahead!) Generally you can't, because the GDI target for window painting is (traditionally) the graphics card's framebuffer and you cannot read from it, only write to it.

(Of course, in practice it is possible to read from the framebuffer, but you shouldn't because it cannot be trusted as another window might overlap yours, or another process might be painting to it in another thread; Also, on modern systems (2006+) with composited window managers each window paints to an offscreen buffer rather than the framebuffer, it is also possible to read from these per-window buffers, but it isn't very fast or optimised - which is why XOR painting is so slow with the DWM on Windows)

For your approach, I suggest using the `DrawToBitmap` method in WinForms which will repaint the window into your own bitmap object:

```
using(Bitmap b = new Bitmap( this.Width, this.Height )) {

    this.DrawToBitmap( b, new Rectangle( 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height ) );

    // Use LockBits here to iterate through each pixel

}
```

I recommend against using `GetPixel`/`SetPixel` because they're very slow and inefficient for iterating through pixels in a bitmap; furthermore it's more efficient to make the outer-loop `y` instead of `x` to take advantage of your CPU's cache (as consecutive `x` values are closer in memory than consecutive `y`values).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. But if you want to get at the pixels of a Control (and a form is just a control) you can use the `Control.DrawToBitmap()` method and then work with the resulting bitmap.

If you want to get at thing that are happening in a special Paint event you should look there, but the final result, after all Paint events have fired will be in the bitmap mentioned above.

If you actually have set a background image (do you?) then you could work with it directly..